# Using .change() to addClass with select list

Tags: onchange

I'm trying to make a hidden field show by adding a class when the "other" option is selected from a pull-down list.  But I'm not quite sure the correct way to do it.

I have the input hidden and when option is chosen I want to add the class "view" which adds display block making the hidden field visible.

Here is a fiddle showing what I have so far, any help would be much appreciated: http://jsfiddle.net/maikunari/NX795/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#select-box").change(function(){
        if($(this).val() == "other"){
            $("#text-field").show();        
        } else {
            $("#text-field").hide();    
        }
    });
});

<select id="select-box">
<option value="Email Newsletter">Email Newsletter</option>
<option value="Yellow Pages ">Yellow Pages </option>
<option id="other-select" value="other">Other</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Dave, but this shows the hidden box right from the start then hides it if I select anything, unless I'm missing something. See my updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maikunari/NX795/3/

Comment: Yes I was missing something, the value="other" in my list of items, works perfectly thank you!